# Visual Studio Mac can't find Xamarin.Android

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

I have a problem in my visual studio for mac, that prevents me from building android apps. 
As you can see in the screenshots I can't even select an android SDK.
[image: Visual Studio Mac Settings]
And my project tells me that Xamarin.Android is not installed.
I already tried reinstalling VisualStudio and `Xamarin.Android` but didn't helped.
[image: Visual Studio Mac Settings]
Does anyone knows whether there is a cache or config file or something else that is maybe wrong and not correctly updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch Visual Studio for Mac and open the Extension Manager (App Menu / Extensions) and make sure that the Android extensions/addins are enabled:

[image]

If they are, check the IDE logs for errors related those extensions:

`Help` / `Open Log Directory`

```
AndroidTools.XXXXXXXX.log
```

and

```
Ide.XXXXXXXX.log
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. In my case it was not the "android development" package that was disabled but the "Forms Project Support". I have no idea "why", but finally after enabling it, everything works again :-) So thank you at least for the tip ;-)